# Chain rule proof. "when $g(x) \neq g(a)$ when $x$ and $a$ are close"

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, chain-rule

Why in the rigorous chain rule proof (exampled at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#History)) do we have to specify $g(x)$ does not equal $g(a)$ as $x$ approaches $a$, but not for a single function definition of a derivative?

Aren't $g(x)$ and $g(a)$ going to be the same for the limit as $x$ approaches $a$ for any function; isn't that true for single function derivatives and the term ($ x - a $) approaching zero on the bottom?

If it is assumed that the limit as $x$ is not equal to $a$ (thus avoiding division by zero), then why can we say for example that the limit as $b$ approaches $1$ of $b$ is equal to $1$?

Comment: You should add some detail more but note that in the limit definition as $x\to a$ we assume that $x\neq a$.

Comment: In some proofs of the chain rule, we need to divide by $g(x)-g(a)$. This will be very small, as $x$ is close to $a$ and $g$ is continuous, but we need it to be different from zero.

Comment: It is very clear what the problem of the OP is. It has to do with bad proofs of the chain rule. But this is over the head of  LStU, JCS and their buddies.

Comment: Could you copy the relevant part of the proof for context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $f\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ at $x$ is defined as
$$
\lim_{a\to x} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.
$$
The expression $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ is defined whenever $x\neq a$. Here $a$ may be arbitrarily close to $x$ but as long as it doesn't *equal* $x$, the expression is well defined.

For the chain rule, you want to rewrite the expression
$$
\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{x-a}
$$
as
$$
\frac{f(g(x))-f(g(a))}{g(x)-g(a)} \cdot \frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}.
$$
For this to be a well defined expression, you still need $x\neq a$ but you also need $g(x)\neq g(a)$. This is a problem since we might have $g(x)=g(a)$ even though $x\neq a$.

For example consider the differentiable function
$$
g(x) =
\begin{cases}
(x+1)^2 & \text{if $x\le -1$}, \\
0 & \text{if $-1\le x\le 1$}, \\
(x-1)^2 & \text{if $1\le x$}.
\end{cases}
$$
When you now want to take the derivative of $f(g(x))$ for some $f$ at $x=0$, you are running into the problem that $g(a)=0=g(0)$ whenever $-1\le a\le 1$, so you can't divide by $g(x)-g(a)$ for $a$ close to $x$, even though you only consider $a\neq x$.

Comment: So this  detail is only necessary to confirm the chain rule for intervals x such that the slope of g(x) is zero?

Comment: Assuming $g$ is differentiable at $x$ this only happens when $g'(x)=0$, yes.

Comment: This may require a new question: how can we assume that the denominator of a derivative (of a single function) is not zero, when a simple limit might express simply that the limit as $b$ approaches $1$ of $b$ is equal to $1$? Doesn't this imply that the denominator would come out as $0$ in terms of $h$, or $a - a$ in terms of $(x - a)$?